# Array problem: pushing a php array into a javascript array, images.url is undefined

Tags: php, html, css, canvas, jss

So I have a dummy array called images. I'm 
pushing a php array into a javascript array to make my real array similar to the form of my dummy array. However when I do this I get images.url is undefined as an error. Even though they look almost almost. The only thing that is different between my example array and my actual array is that the real array is a part of a path to an image `shelf/thumbnail/O191/6337/O1916337-00.png` and my dummy array is a link to an image. Does my path have to be my full path to my image for my code to work??? The full path to my image should be /check/assets/img/shelf/thumbnail/O191/6337/O1916337-00.png .

Here is how the console looks like for my real array after pushing it into images [image]

This is how the console looks like for my dummy array.
[image]

The form of the array should be fine for my real array, yet I still get images.url is undefined and I'm not exactly sure why. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

```js
 document.body.onload = createHTML;

  /// my real array where I put $face into images.
  //    const images = [];
  //      images.push(<?= json_encode($face) ?>);
  //     console.log(images); 
   

      let index = 0;
      const display = "table"; // or "grid" if horizontal, but this migh depend where you place the rest of the code, cause i added the style to the body
      const x = 0;
      const y = 0;

         // dummy array
       const images = {
             height: 100,
             width: 100,
             url: [
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F8%2F84%2FAssociation_of_Gay_and_Lesbian_Psychiatrists_logo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fnewsgraphics%2F2016%2F07%2F14%2Fpluto-one-year%2Fassets%2Ficon-pluto.png&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.oFxADNN67dYP-ke5xg7HbQHaHG%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glassdoor.com%2Fsqll%2F1065746%2Felevation-church-squarelogo-1453223965790.png&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F8%2F84%2FAssociation_of_Gay_and_Lesbian_Psychiatrists_logo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fnewsgraphics%2F2016%2F07%2F14%2Fpluto-one-year%2Fassets%2Ficon-pluto.png&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.oFxADNN67dYP-ke5xg7HbQHaHG%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glassdoor.com%2Fsqll%2F1065746%2Felevation-church-squarelogo-1453223965790.png&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fen%2F8%2F84%2FAssociation_of_Gay_and_Lesbian_Psychiatrists_logo.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic01.nyt.com%2Fnewsgraphics%2F2016%2F07%2F14%2Fpluto-one-year%2Fassets%2Ficon-pluto.png&f=1&nofb=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.oFxADNN67dYP-ke5xg7HbQHaHG%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
                   "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.glassdoor.com%2Fsqll%2F1065746%2Felevation-church-squarelogo-1453223965790.png&f=1&nofb=1",
                   ""
             ]
       }; 

       console.log(images);




      function createHTML() {
            console.log("E: Execute & R: Request & I: Informative");
            //loop to go true all images
            document.body.style.display = display;
            for (const image of images.url) {
                  //each image will correspond to a canvas element
                  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                  //each canvas element will has is own properties (in this case all the same)
                  canvas.id = "option" + [index];
                  var canId = canvas.id;
                  canvas.height = images.height;
                  canvas.width = images.width;
                  canvas.style.padding = "10px";
                  //function to get the corresponded image of that particular canvas element
                  drawImages(canvas);
                  //add an event listener for when a user click on the particular canvas
                  canvas.addEventListener("click", optionClick, false);
                  //all html part was handle we can append it to the body
                  // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  div.id = canvas.id;
                  document.getElementById('suitei-slider').appendChild(div);
                  document.getElementById(div.id).appendChild(canvas);
                  index++;
            }
      }

      function drawImages(canvas) {
            //we need to use the getContext canvas function to draw anything inside the canvas element
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            const background = new Image();

            // for text

            //This is needed because if the drawImage is called from a different place that the createHTML function
            //index value will not be at 0 and it will for sure with an heigher id that the one expected
            //so we are using regex to remove all letters from the canvas.id and get the number to use it later
            index = canvas.id.replace(/\D/g, "");

            //console.log('E: Drawing image ' + index + ' on canvas ' + canvas.id);

            //get the image url using the index to get the corresponded image
            background.src = images.url[index];
            //no idea why but to place the image, we need to use the onload event
            //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage
            background.onload = function() {
                  ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            };
            background.onerror = function() {
                  const text = "インバ ど";
                  ctx.fillText(text, 0, 0 + 10 * 1);
            };
      }

      function drawX(canvas) {
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            console.log("E: Placing X on canvas " + canvas.id);

            /*
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(images.width, images.height);
            ctx.moveTo(images.height, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(0, images.width);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke(); */

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(50, 50, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.lineWidth = 5;
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
            const text = "インバ ど";

      }

      function fillTextLine(canvas, x, y) {
            var text = "インバ ど";
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var textList = text.split("　");
            var lineHeight = ctx.measureText("あ").width;
            textList.forEach(function(text, i) {
                  ctx.fillText(text, x, y + lineHeight * i);
            });
      }



      function clear(canvas) {
            console.log("E: clearing canvas " + canvas.id);

            canvas.getContext("2d").clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            drawImages(canvas);
      }

      function optionClick(e) {
            log = true;
            const canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
            for (const option of canvas) {
                  if (log)
                        console.log("I: User clicked at option " + e.target.id + ":" + option.id);
                  log = false;
                  if (e.target.id === option.id) {
                        console.log("R: Drawing request at canvas " + option.id);
                        drawX(option);
                  } else {
                        console.log("R: Clearing request at canvas " + option.id);
                        clear(option);
                  }
            }
      }



      //We start by calling createHTML (that will handle with all HTML elements)
      //window.onload = createHTML;
      document.body.onload = createHTML;
```

```css
canvas.suiteiCanvas {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;

  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 150px;

  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
}

#draw-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 16px 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

img.new {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;

  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 150px;

  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);

}

.multiple-items{
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="multiple-items" id="suitei-slider">
  
  </div>
</body>
```

The file paths that are put into $result_thumbnail are processed by PHP in my controller.

```
<?php $face = [
            'height' => 100,
            'width' => 100,
            'url' => $result_thumbnail,
        ];
```

Comment: `const images = <?php echo json_encode( $face );?>;` - otherwise elements will be at `images[0]`

Comment: good news, good luck with the rest of your coding adventure